# The Sand Scrunched Beneath My Feet

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was reading Ivan Klima's *[No Saints Or Angels](http://books.google.com/books?id=8ph67I9VUQcC&pg=PA189&lpg=PA189&dq=the%20sand%20scrunched%20beneath%20my%20feet&source=bl&ots=DgizF_kHXK&sig=SnEiGDxmVWDIQLSxWql4TvRcp34&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ei=T5msU4j8KczAoATOxICACQ&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBA)* and found the highlighted part in the following sentence not quite clear:

> When Karel<sup>1</sup> left me, I tried to give her<sup>2</sup> that love, but it’s impossible just to go on giving; well I wasn’t able to, at least. There were moments when my loneliness weighed heavily on me; *the sand scrunched beneath my feet* and I thirsted. I yearned for a loving man; I yearned for him so much that lovers would come to me in my dreams...

1: Karel is the ex-husband of the female protagonist in the story;
2: "Her" here refers to the female protagonist's daughter.

I cannot quite make out why the feeling of sand spreading and thinning (not sure if it is the right interpretation for scrunching) is associated with loneliness and yearning for love.

Comment: In her imagination she casts her loneliness as being marooned on the beach of a waterless island.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about literary interpretation.

Comment: Hi, Phenry. Not actually about literary interpretation.Before reading Stoney's comment, I actually thought the "crunching" is a pleasant experience like http://www.southernsamplerartistscolony.com/sand-between-my-toes-by-cindy-rasicot/.

Answer (score 1):

In her moments of loneliness, the narrator imagines herself in an emotional desert, a trackless, waterless (hence the thirst) expanse of sand.

Klima's choice of *[scrunch](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/scrunch)* to convey the sound of the imagined sand beneath the narrator's feet is telling, denoting as it does "a loud noise like something being *crushed*."

Comment: Are you sure that this is the right definition, not [become crushed or squeezed into a compact mass.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/scrunch?q=scrunch)

Comment: It's coherent, in context, with [other `SKR-` words](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/skr.pdf)

Comment: `scrunch` is onomatopoeia here surely.

Comment: Partially. _Scrunch_ gets `2-Dimensional Contact`, `Compress/Disarray`, `Diminutive`, and `Aural` [in the link](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/skr.pdf). So there **is** an aural component. But there are three other semantic dimensions, appealing to other senses than sound, so it's not really onomatopoeia.